# How to implement a button on a jQuery Sortable accordion header

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I've been working on a jQuery custom sortable accordion for my website. The next stage to implement is a button on each header of the sortable accordion which will delete the section expandable list from the jQuery sortable accordion.

I have the code ready to use, however I cannot seem to overlay the button on the header without it being part of the header on click function to expand or drag function to sort, however I do want it to follow the the accordion upon being sorted.

```
function create_accordian(str) {
    $( str )
    .accordion({
        header: '> div > h3',
        autoHeight: false,
        active: false,
        collapsible: true,
    })
    .sortable({
        axis: 'y',
        handle: 'h3',
        stop: function( event, ui ) {
            // IE doesn't register the blur when sorting
            // so trigger focusout handlers to remove .ui-state-focus
            ui.item.children( 'h3' ).triggerHandler( 'focusout' );
        }
    });
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JF7PD/4/)

I have tried modifying the CSS for the position tributes of the delete feature, the above jQuery code for where the header is defined, wrapping both in a `div` and defining the header separately. All my efforts have come to a dead end.

I need to be able to have a delete icon on each header which moves whilst being sorted and has a separate on click function so it does not expand or drag the accordion.

Best Regards,
Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two sets of updates to achieve the desired goal. Note I added a class of `.RemoveSection` to your `<span>` with the 'X' icon to facilitate these examples.

First, create a `.click()` handler for the 'X' icon you have and in its first step, use `.stopPropagation()` ([reference here](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)) to ensure its click event does not bubble up to the jQ UI sortable:

```
$('.RemoveSection').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Next, leverage the `cancel` option ([reference here](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-cancel)) for the jQ UI sortable widget to exclude your 'X' icon from being a handle for sorting:

```
.sortable({
    axis: 'y',
    handle: 'h3',
    cancel: '.RemoveSection', // This excludes your 'X' icon
    stop: function( event, ui ) {
        // IE doesn't register the blur when sorting
        // so trigger focusout handlers to remove .ui-state-focus
        ui.item.children( 'h3' ).triggerHandler( 'focusout' );
    }
});
```

Updated jsFiddle, forked from yours: http://jsfiddle.net/2aLec/2/

While I did not actually add the script to delete the sortable section, give it a go & post back if you need help. Your general approach should be to simply traverse up the DOM from your 'X' icon to the parent header, then remove it & its sibling `<div>` (and maybe kick off a `.refresh()` of the sortable for good measure).

Comment: This is almost exactly what I am looking for +1 @Stevangelista thank you. The remove script I am not looking for, the only additional help would be to be able to have it's own on hover. As you hover over the x icon, the header on hover shows. Can this be prevented and on hover of my x icon the background image changes? Don't worry about an image url, I'll be using the same icons but a red version.

Comment: This updated jsFiddle does that: http://jsfiddle.net/2aLec/14/ - I had to hardcode the image path to get the background gradient to apply but I venture that may be due to running in jsFiddle. I put comments into the relevant code since it's too much to squeeze into a comment here.

Comment: Don't want to make this off-topic and leave this as an unaccepted answer as it works perfectly, I'm just having problems to the left of the x where it is over the header but does not do the on hover for the header. I've just woken up and it's probably simple so I'll keep working on this but if you're around it would be something I could use help on.

Comment: This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2aLec/15/http://jsfiddle.net/2aLec/15/) I've somewhat solved this issue apart from the top of the X whilst being not on the X but elsewhere on the header section :)

Comment: Tim, I believe this is what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/2aLec/19/ - I've forked your jsFiddle & updated it with some new CSS (commented at the top). Specifically, the `height` & `width` aren't required and I removed the `padding` that was creating those "dead zones" where you weren't over the 'X' but also not getting the accordion header hover-effect. Now, the header's hover works anywhere besides directly over the 'X' icon.